# What is wrong with my sql "group by" and "having" statement?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I keep getting an error saying this is not a group by expression when i run this statement in oracle XE.

```
SELECT PROJECTID, HOURSWORKED FROM ASSIGNMENT GROUP BY PROJECTID HAVING HOURSWORKED > 20;
```

[image: Table: ASSIGNMENT]

Comment: You need an aggregate like `SUM(HOURSWORKED) > 20`, or remove the whole group by and add `WHERE HOURSWORKED > 20`.  Whichever is your intention.

Comment: Hint:  `SUM(hoursworked)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an aggregate function on hoursworked - e.g. MAX(HOURSWORKED), AVERAGE(HOURSWORKED) etc.  Or you also have to add it to the group by, though that would seem strange..

One other suggestion for asking SQL questions on stackoverflow - create a minimal test case using SQL Fiddle.  E.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fea91/5 for your example.  Unless it's something very Oracle specific, Postgres is usually close enough for ordinary SQL questions.  Try changing the WHERE to a HAVING, to see the difference between the two...

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is used for an aggregating expression, such as `MAX()` or `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write

```
SELECT PROJECTID, HOURSWORKED 
FROM ASSIGNMENT 
WHERE HOURSWORKED > 20;
```

or

```
SELECT PROJECTID, SUM(HOURSWORKED) 
FROM ASSIGNMENT 
GROUP BY PROJECTID 
HAVING SUM(HOURSWORKED) > 20;
```

(or some other aggregate function, eg: MAX, MIN) depending on your intent.

`WHERE` is used to filter individual records

`HAVING` is used to filter the grouped aggregate values.